# AttributeError: 'Seekerskillset' object has no attribute 'skill_name'

Tags: django, django-views, bulkinsert

> I am trying to implement bulk_create my inserting multiple objects in
> a relation, not sure whether I am doing it right i have added trace back as well  below is skill set model

```
class Skillset(models.Model):
    skill_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.skill_name
```

**my view**

```
skill_name = request.POST.getlist('skill_name')
        skill_level = request.POST.getlist('skill_level')
        print(f'skill name-> {skill_name} skill level ->{skill_level}')
        seeker_skll = []
        # testing destructing
        for skill_nme, skill_lvl in zip(skill_name, skill_level):
            skill_set = Skillset.objects.get(skill_name=skill_nme)
            seeker_skll.append(Seekerskillset(
                skill_set=skill_set, skill_level=skill_lvl, seeker=user))

        seeker_skll = Skillset.objects.bulk_create(seeker_skll)
        print(seeker_skll)
        return redirect('/users/dashboard')
```

**Model**

```
class Seekerskillset(models.Model):
    skill_set = models.ForeignKey(Skillset, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seeker = models.ForeignKey(SeekerProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill_level = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Seeker skill set'
```

**error i am getting**

> AttributeError: 'Seekerskillset' object has no attribute 'skill_name'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj\mysite_jobportal\seekerbuilder\views.py", line 43, in update_details
    seeker_skll = Skillset.objects.bulk_create(seeker_skll)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 515, in bulk_create
    objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts,
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1293, in _batched_insert
    self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db, ignore_conflicts=ignore_conflicts)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1415, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1360, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1360, in <listcomp>
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1359, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1310, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 822, in pre_save
    return getattr(model_instance, self.attname)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/app_det/
Exception Value: 'Seekerskillset' object has no attribute 'skill_name'
```

Comment: Can you share the whole traceback and the model with the field skill name

Comment: i have added it @bdbd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by using `Skillset` to bulk create `Seekerskillset` objects.

So change:

```
seeker_skll = Skillset.objects.bulk_create(seeker_skll)
```

to:

```
seeker_skll = Seekerskillset.objects.bulk_create(seeker_skll)
```

Comment: fool of me how i couldn't see that :p thanks so much

Comment: It happens. No worries!

Comment: i have run into another problem, return object is showing none which means data was not pushed into the database `[<Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>, <Seekerskillset: Seekerskillset object (None)>]` i am printing the result

Comment: Check if your for loop generates the objects in the list before bulk create